# Multiprocess with Serial Object as Parameter

Tags: python, parameters, serial-port, multiprocessing, modem

I'm having a problem with Python and passing a serial object as a parameter to a separate process. The program is being run in Windows 8, so using global variables isn't an option.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import serial
from serial.tools import list_ports
from time import sleep

displayMessages = Queue()
modemPort = None

def processDisplayMessages(displayMessages):
    while True:
        msg = displayMessages.get()  #should halt until message in queue
        print msg

def processIncomingSerialMessages(modemPort, displayMessages):
    while True:
        line = modemPort.readline()
        displayMessages.put(line)

def main():
    print "Serial Send Test"
    Process(target=processDisplayMessages, args = (displayMessages,)).start()
    modemPort = serial.Serial('COM5', 57600, timeout=0.9)  # open first serial port
    Process(target=processIncomingSerialMessages, args = (modemPort, displayMessages)).start()
    print "Back from launch"

    sleep(0.1)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When the program runs I get the following error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.parets\Documents\..Development\RaspberryPi\windows\seri
alRecvPrototype.py", line 27, in processIncomingSerialMessages
    line = modemPort.readline()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 246, in read
    if not self.hComPort: raise portNotOpenError
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'hComPort'
```

If I place the open for the serial port (modemPort) as the first line of processIncomingSerialMessages the program works fine. The issue is that I need to decouple input and output from the modem so I need to pass the serial object as a parameter. And Python doesn't seem to like that.

Can anyone see the mistake I am making, or can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't run this code, but I'd be amazed if it worked:  an argument passed across processes works by pickling the argument object on the sending side, sending the pickle string across processes via a pipe or a socket, and unpickling that string on the receiving side.  I know of no case of any open I/O-kind-of-object for which this can possibly work (files, sockets, pipes ...).  I/O-kinds-of-objects don't *just* have internal data state, they're also connected to resources that Python itself doesn't implement.  A pickle is just a stream of raw bytes.

You already figured out that you have to open the serial port in the worker process.  Alas, I don't know what "I need to decouple input and output from the modem" means, so it's hard to suggest a workaround.  But I'm sure you'll figure it out if you accept what you've already discovered the hard way:  passing an open serial object across processes is never going to work.

That said, you could dig into the various pickling protocols and build your own class with custom pickling/unpickling code that (re)opened a serial object when unpickled.  That would be an elaborate way to hide what would otherwise be straightforward code to (re)open a serial object in worker processes.

**EDIT: Q&A**

> And again windows doesn't offer the easy way out of global variables, so I'm stuck with a single process handing both send and receive.

A "global variable" probably wouldn't help you. I assume you have `fork()` in mind, but nothing is *shared* across `fork()` either: child processes see *copies* of the parent process's address space. I/O gimmicks often fail to work correctly then too.

> Does Python provide a way to pass a value by reference, or a reference value to a process? I have tried add the serial object to lists and sets with the same results. Again, does Python provide something like an Object or an Array from Java where I could get a reference through without it being "Pickled"?

There's a very high wall between processes in all modern OSes. To get anything truly shared across processes you need to use types built from the ground up for that, or use the OS's "shared memory" facilities.

You can read the docs for `multiprocessing.sharedctypes`, which supplies ways to use shared (across processes) memory.  But, as the docs warn:

> Note
>   Although it is possible to store a pointer in shared memory remember that this will refer to a location in the address space of a specific process. However, the pointer is quite likely to be invalid in the context of a second process and trying to dereference the pointer from the second process may cause a crash.

It's not going to work.  This isn't a programming language issue, it's an OS issue.  `sharedctypes` is useful for things like arrays of ints and floats.

> For this application to work (live telemetry) the receive process has to remain live at all times.

Sorry, I'm not following that in context.  You said in your question:  "If I place the open for the serial port (modemPort) as the first line of processIncomingSerialMessages the program works fine.".  `processIncomingSerialMessages` has an infinite loop following that.  In what sense does that violate "the receive process has to remain live at all times"?

In the code you showed, it doesn't *appear* to make a lick of difference whether the serial port is opened in a worker process or in the main process (if the latter actually worked), and indeed you said it worked fine if you did it the former way.  So what exactly is wrong with doing it that way?  Indeed, why use a worker process at all for that?  The main program you showed does nothing (except sleep for a tenth of a second) after starting both workers, so why not let the main program *be* "the receive process"?

Comment: Decoupling: placing the input and the output in separate processes. For this application to work (live telemetry) the receive process has to remain live at all times. Shutting the port down risks lost data and I might as well deal with send and receive in the same process. And again windows doesn't offer the easy way out of global variables, so I'm stuck with a single process handing both send and receive.

Comment: The details of how Python handles the argument passing is interesting. If I'm reading your description properly, the "pickled" variables are sent by value and something IO bound like my serial object wouldn't survive the transfer. Does Python provide a way to pass a value by reference, or a reference value to a process? I have tried add the serial object to lists and sets with the same results. Again, does Python provide something like an Object or an Array from Java where I could get a reference through without it being "Pickled"?

Comment: The code example is simply a prototype. I'm trying to hash out back and forth serial communications with multiple processes before I add it into the main program. By its nature as a prototype, this example is completely pointless. The read process reads. The write process writes. And the display process displays. Nothing else. In the full application the read process would continuously read in data at all times without pause. I want to avoid the complexity of writing in the process keeping it simple and guaranteeing that all reads are accepted and stored. Thus the reason to put write elsewhere

Comment: Spawning a new process in the Python implementation on other platforms produces a subprocess that has access to all of the data from the parent process. Thus a simple global variable will be accessible from any process if the program is running in Linux. Windows doesn't do subprocesses. Each new process is clean, from scratch, with no data shared from the spawning process. Hence the need to pass parameters into the process with shared data. This works fine with a data structure like a Queue, but for various reasons does not work for hardware bound structures like serial.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't given a reason for why "the read process" can't open the port it's reading from. That's the obvious way to do it, and it will work fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't work correctly on Linux with a `Queue.Queue`.  It works with a `multiprocessing.Queue` because that's an example of a type "built from the ground up for that" (inter-process communication) - and a `multiprocessing.Queue` is quite a complex beast under the covers to support that.

Comment: Python and the OS blocks multiple resources from access the same serial "file". Once one process has it open for reading, another can't open it to write to. It has to be open in a single place and then shared.

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize that. Then you're out of luck. This would be easy to do with threads (within a single process), though. Have you considered that?

Comment: And yes it does work. I have a functioning prototype on the Linux side that opens the serial connection as its first job as a global variable. That variable being in a share scope is easily accessible to all of the processes. It isn't passed as a parameter at all. And yes, I am aware of the need and use of multiprocessing.Queue as the above prototype shows.

Comment: I wasn't absolute about the "global variable" - I said "I/O gimmicks often fail to work correctly then too." It's nice that it worked on Linux, but that's no guarantee it would also work on Windows (if Windows had `fork()`). This stuff is much more complicated than I think you currently appreciate ;-)

Comment: I selected separate processes to avoid "lock-step" behavior and blocking from other hardware that the final program will be interacting with. Threads may be the solution to the shared resource issue, but for this application the best solution will probably be a single serial process with carefully balanced send and receive that avoids blocking at all costs... which represents a lot more development time. :-/