# Python shared memory string variable: 'SynchronizedArray has no Attribute value'

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, ctypes, shared-memory

i recently got a Problem with Multiprocessing in Python 3.9.2 on a Raspberry Pi. Following this question: [Python shared string memory for multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816222/python-shared-string-memory-for-multiprocessing)
To implement a Shared Memory Variable, which can store a String. But i stumbled into a problem, that i could set the .value attribute but if i wanted to print it and return it i got the Following Error: 'SynchronizedArray has no Attribute value'. I did this to have a custom mulitprocessing.Event() with an specific Error Description.

In the following code you can see that i pass the custom event into the subprocess and i catch it in the mainprocess. I tried RawArray('c_char_p', 255) and Array('c_char', 255) but i ended up with the same error. Also the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) says that

> Note that an array of ctypes.c_char has value and raw attributes which allow one to use it to store and retrieve strings.

I dont know if the docs are just wrong or i implemented something wrong.

manager.py:

```
        [..]
        self.manager = Manager()
        
        with self.manager as m:
            # Shared Memory for Random Bits
            randomValues = Queue()
            stopEvent = Event()
            # Pass SharedMemory String into the custom event.
            errorEvent = ErrorEvent(Array(c_char, 255))

            # Start the generation of random values
            videoProc = Process(target=ObjectTracker.CapturePendelum, args=(stopEvent, errorEvent, randomValues))
            videoProc.start()


            if(errorEvent.isEventSet()):
                stopEvent.set()
                raise Exception(errorEvent.getErrorDescription())
            [...]
```

ErrorEvent.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Event

class ErrorEvent():
    def __init__ (self, shareMemVar):
        super().__init__()
        self.__event = Event()
        self.__description = shareMemVar
    
    def setEvent(self):
        self.__event.set()
    
    def getEvent(self):
        return self.__event
    
    def isEventSet(self):
        return self.__event.is_set()
    
    def setErrorDescription(self, errorDescription):
        self.__description.value = errorDescription

    def getErrorDescription(self):
        return self.__description.value
```

My Exception occurs in the line: "return self.__description.value". I just cant figure out, why i can set the .value attribute but dont return it(neither print it right there.).

I tried calling the multiprocessing.Array() with all diffrent ctypes e. g. c_char_p, c_wchar_p, c_char, c_wchar. Nothing worked.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the issue? I found some other comments online that makes it seems like it may be an issue with a specific version of python https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/8799