# When using string shared memory in Python's multiprocessing alongside Kivy, it causes an error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy, shared-memory

I have tried using **shared memory for strings with the following simple Python code, and it works well**.

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process, Lock

def process1(array,  lock):
    with lock:
        buffer_data = str("z1111").encode("utf-8")
        array[0:len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = Array('c', 35)
    lock = Lock()

    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[array, lock], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test1.join()
    
    print(array[:].decode("utf-8"))
    print("process ended")
```

Next, I tried implementing **shared memory for numbers using a GUI library called Kivy, and that worked well** too.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, set_start_method, freeze_support, Lock

kvLoadString=("""
<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "start"
            font_size: 48
            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: 'result'
""")

def start_process(count,lock):
    process_test = Process(target=p_test, args=[count,lock], daemon=True)
    process_test.start()
    return process_test

def p_test(count,lock):
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
        with lock:
            count.value = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() 
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
    from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty,NumericProperty,ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
    from kivy.uix.button import Button

    set_start_method('spawn')


    class TestApp(App):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.title = 'testApp'

        def build(self):
            return TextWidget()

    class TextWidget(Widget):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.process_test = None
            self.proc = None

            # shared memory
            self.count = Value('i', 0)
            self.lock = Lock()

        def buttonClicked(self):
            if self.ids.button1.text == "start":
                self.proc = start_process(self.count,self.lock)
                self.ids.button1.text = "stop"
            else:
                if self.proc:
                    self.proc.kill()
                self.ids.button1.text = "start"
                self.ids.lab.text = str(self.count.value)

    Builder.load_string(kvLoadString)
    TestApp().run()
```

However, I did **not succeed in using Kivy with shared memory for strings** as follows.

```
from multiprocessing import Array,Process, Value, set_start_method, freeze_support, Lock
import math

kvLoadString=("""
<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "start"
            font_size: 48
            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: 'result'
""")

def start_process(array,lock):
    process_test = Process(target=p_test, args=[array,lock], daemon=True)
    process_test.start()
    return process_test

def p_test(array,lock):
    with lock:
        buffer_data = str("z1111").encode("utf-8")
        array[0:len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
        print(array.decode("utf-8"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() 
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
    from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty,NumericProperty,ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
    from kivy.uix.button import Button

    set_start_method('spawn')


    class TestApp(App):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.title = 'testApp'

        def build(self):
            return TextWidget()

    class TextWidget(Widget):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.process_test = None
            self.proc = None

            # shared memory
            self.array = Array('c', 35)
            self.lock = Lock()

        def buttonClicked(self):
            if self.ids.button1.text == "start":
                self.proc = start_process(self.array,self.lock)
                self.ids.button1.text = "stop"
            else:
                if self.proc:
                    self.proc.kill()
                self.ids.button1.text = "start"
                self.ids.lab.text = self.array.decode("utf-8")

    Builder.load_string(kvLoadString)
    TestApp().run()
```

The error message is as follows. How can I avoid such an error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\Winpython64-3.9.10.0\WPy64-39100\python-3.9.10.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\Winpython64-3.9.10.0\WPy64-39100\python-3.9.10.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taichi\Desktop\test.py", line 29, in p_test
    print(array.decode("utf-8"))
AttributeError: 'SynchronizedString' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: You may find this discussion useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816222/python-shared-string-memory-for-multiprocessing

Comment: As I demonstrated in the example, shared memory works well with simple code. However, the main issue of this question is that it does not behave as expected when combined with Kivy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was tricky, as it turned out it was not a kivy issue.  Try the following to convert array or self.array into a string:

```
s = bytes.join(b'', [c for c in array if c != b'\x00']).decode('utf-8')
```